# How to change Bump Map height

Tags: texturing

[image]I'm using a black and white bump map image to carve a image from an object but when I change the height it only bumps a little. If increase the height nothing really changes. How can I change the height/depth of my bump map?

Comment: add a math->Multiply node so that you can scale the values.

Comment: @cegaton still nothing really happens the height always stays the same whatever value it gets

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that might help us understand your scene and settings. ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))

Comment: @cegaton I've added my node setup

Comment: If you have a full black and full white image, there is no height-- the only thing that matters in a bump map is the change in value, which in your pic, exists along only a single pixel border.  You really can't get away with using a 1-bit color image as a bump map-- there's very little point to it.  If you want your bump map to look better, pop it in GIMP and run a gaussian blur on it first.  After that, changes in height will become more apparent.

Answer (score 5):

At first of course, use an app like CrazyBump or else to convert your picture to a **DISP** picture.

Then: **Image Texture** node (*Non-Color Data* mode) -> (Color Output) -> *Height* input of a **Bump node** -> *Normal* input of a **Diffuse** node -> **Material Output** node. Play with the *Strength* value of the *Bump* node to increase the effect.

As Cegaton said, if necessary, you can increase the effect with a *Converter* > **Math** node (*Multiply* mode) between the *Image Texture* and the *Bump* (you could also try a *Converter* > *ColorRamp* node between the *Bump* and the *Diffuse*).

[image]

Here I've used your file, set a simpler material, and played a bit with the different values of CrazyBump, it gives a bit of blur and grey, you can get something better than what you can get with a simple B&W picture, but you can't simulate a deep engraving, especially if you don't have any image texture that goes along and that could help to fake it...

[image]

BlenderForNoobs has made a video on this topic, you can see that you can only fake a slight engraving: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWB5XVK7-VI&

Also maybe try to blur the b&w bump image, it may give better result.

Comment: I have the same setup but nothing changes (added image of my setup in my first post). The image I'm using is kind of a stencil.

Comment: we lack information, for example, what your map looks like? Even with a black & white picture I can get a correct result, as long as I convert it to a DISP picture of course. Perhaps share your file, and don't forget to pack the image as PNG: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The background is totally black (#fff) with totally white(#000) stars on it.The image has 8k size and has the PNG format.

Comment: again, you need to convert it to a DISP picture with an app like CrazyBump, or with a online converter, have you done it?

Comment: The image I'm using is already a black and white image. Using Crazybump to convert a b/w image to an DISP image doesn't give great results.

Comment: could you please share your DISP image (or your file) so that we can try?

Comment: Sure, here it is: (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5913/)

Comment: I've edited my answer, I've played a bit with the CrazyBump values, anyway you will never simulate a depth like a topology, especially if you only count on the Bump node

Answer (score 4):

Bump Map is very subtle, if you need more depth, try with displacement.

[image]

Good Luck